# How to find out which line was selected in one GWT grid canvas?

Tags: java, gwt, java-canvas

I'm working on one GWT grid Canvas like [this in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2yJn/66/)

My `gridCanvas` Object has horizontal lines represent paths. Also the object has vertical lines that represent sections.

I want to know how I could get the user's selection, for example, if the user has selected a route or a section and which route or section is selected.

Here a 
[screenshot](http://www.jperezmedina.eu/grid/gridCanvasExample.png) of case.

Answer (score 0):

Add the event you want to listen to like `gridCanvas.addClickHandler(ClickHandler)` and use the `ClickEvent` to obtain the mouse position and calculate the cell the user clicked on.

```
gridCanvas.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
       int row = event.getY() / getCellHeight();
       int col = event.getX() / getCellWidth();
   }
});
```

With `getX()` and `getY()`, you obtain the position of the mouse. Since you constructed the grid, you should also have the width and height of a cell. With this information, it is then easy to get the row and/or column.

I made a full sample that you can find [here](https://github.com/nmorel/canvas-grid-test/blob/master/src/main/java/zer/client/App.java).

The sample is deployed [here](http://nmorel.github.io/canvas-grid-test/).

Comment: Very nice your example. In my case i need select the lines not the cells. I'actualized the question with one screenshot

Comment: You could generate a Map<Integer, Integer> for horizontal lines and vertical lines when you construct the grid. The key is the x/y position, the value the index or any object that represents your line. And then use the `event.getX()`and `event.getY()` to find the line

Comment: If your lines are larger than 1px or if you want your user to select the line even if he click 1px above, you'll need a more complex approach. A bit like a Map but where the key is a range and the equality is based on intersection.